# Recursive Filter/Search function

Tags: javascript

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/EddTally/jsa69f7r/3/#&togetherjs=zMFpAQcRTt

Those who cannot access JSFiddle:

```
/**
 * Utilizes recursion to search through an item of any type (currently accepted types are object, array and string)
 * to find if it contains such a value.
 *  
 * @param item
 * @param value
 */
    function filterItem(item, value){
        // Isn't object
        if(typeof item == 'string'){
                return filterString(item, value) 
            } // Is Array
            else if(Array.isArray(item)){
                return filterArray(item, value)
            } // Is Object
            else{
                return filterObj(item, value)
            }
        }
/**
 * Checks if an object contains the value by recursively calling the filterItem function to work it's way through the obj.
 * 
 * @param obj
 * @param value
 */
    const filterObj = (obj, value) => {
        let contains = false;
        for(let [key, val] of Object.entries(obj)){
            if(key.toString().toLowerCase().includes(value)){
                contains = true
                break;
            }else{
                if(filterItem(val, value)){
                    contains = true
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return contains
    }
    /**
 * Used in the recursive function above, goes all the way down until it reaches the base string, then would return 
 * the result of the .includes() funtion.
 * 
 * @param array
 * @param value
 */
    const filterArray = (array, value) => {
        let contains = false;
        for(let x of array){
            if(filterItem(x, value)){
                contains = true
                break;
            }
        }
        return contains
    }
    /**
 * Checks if an string contains the value
 * @param string
 * @param value
 */
    const filterString = (string, value) => {
        return string.toString().toLowerCase().includes(value)
    }
  
  let exampleObj = {"hi": ["five", "twenty", {"11": 44, "eggs": ["egge"]}]}
  console.log(filterItem(exampleObj, "egge")) //Should come back true
```

I am wondering if this search/filter function is good or not, any potential things I may have missed out on or things to make it better.

Answer (score 4):

From a short review;

- The function name is a bit misleading, it does not filter anything really. Could be named `hasValue`, or even `hasString`
- You could also just return the occurrence(s) of where the string is found, this could be more useful
- `typeof` returns more than you handle
- Personally, I would make the `toLowerCase()` call only if requested by the caller
- `filterObj` should call `filterString` instead of `toString().toLowerCase().includes`
- Your ratio of comments vs. code is too high in places like this;

  ```
    /**
     * Checks if an string contains the value
     * @param string
     * @param value
    **/
    const filterString = (string, value) => {
        return string.toString().toLowerCase().includes(value)
    }
  ```

My rewrite would be something like this;
This one actually filters/returns all matches

```js
function filterString(haystack, needle){

  let type = typeof haystack;  //"undefined", "object", "boolean", "number", "bigint", "string", "symbol", "function"
  //JS.. null is an object
  type = haystack===null?"undefined":type;
    
  if(Array.isArray(haystack)){
    return haystack.map(v => filterString(v, needle)).flat();
  }else if(type == "object"){
    return Object.keys(haystack).concat(Object.values(haystack)).map(v => filterString(v, needle)).flat();
  }else if(type == "undefined"){
      return (haystack+'').includes(needle)?[haystack]:[];
  }else{
    return haystack.toString().includes(needle)?[haystack]:[];
  }
}
      
let example = {"hi": [console.log,{ thisIsNull:null, thisIsUndefined:undefined } ,4044, "five", "twenty", {"11": 44, "eggs": ["egge"]}]}
console.log(filterString(example, "egg"));
console.log(filterString(example, "console"));
console.log(filterString(example, 44));
console.log(filterString(example, null));
console.log(filterString(example, undefined));
```

Comment: You need Node 11 or higher

Comment: Warning your function will convert functions to strings including the source in the search, EG `filterString({test(){var B=0}}, "B"))` will return the function `test(){var B=0}`

Comment: Yep, I thought that was kind of cool

Comment: Yes, the function name is misleading.
Too much duplicated code, check.
In terms of ratio for comments vs code, I enjoy the practice of having the JSDoc popup when I hover over the function I'm using, but I should remove this if the code itself is too small?
Thank you.

Comment: @Tally I would, I seem to parse faster the code than the comment.

Answer (score 3):

## Bugs

Your code will throw errors if you include `null`, or `undefined` in the data.

And your code does not check for cyclic data structures.

First some review points.

---

## Review

Some general review points regarding code style and language feature use.

### Use `RegExp`

Rather than use [String.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) convert the search term to a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) with the case insensitive flag. You can then test without the need to convert to lower case. Eg `const match = new RegExp(value, "gi");`  See example for more.

In this case [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) has additional functionality that will help solve the bugs.

### Use `===` not `==`

Alwyas use [=== (Strict equality)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) and [!== (Strict inequality)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_inequality) rather than [== (Equality)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality) and [!= (Inequality)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Inequality)

### `const`

Use [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) for variables that do not change. For example the line `for(let [key, val] of Object.entries(obj)){` should be `for(const [key, val] of Object.entries(obj)){`

### Reduce code noise

Don't add `else` / `else if` statements after you `return` in the previous statement block.

Example

```
if (foo) {
    return 0;
} else {
    return 1;
}

// should be

if (foo) {
    return 0;
}
return 1;
```

### Use the language

Your code has not utilized appropriate language features.

You can use [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check the content of an array of at least one match. That includes the array of entries from [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

### Rewrite

Thus it could be rewritten as follows..

```
function filterItem(item, value){
    const match = new RegExp(value, "gi");  
    return (function filter(item){       
        if (item === null) { return false }
        if (typeof item !== 'object') { return match.test(item) }
        return Array.isArray(item) ? 
            item.some(item => filter(item)) :
            Object.entries(item).some(([key, item]) => filter(key) || filter(item));
    })(item);
}
```

The code checks for `null` assuming that you will not be searching for such. This is needed because [null](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null) is a type of `Object`.

The code also does the string match for any item that is not an `Object` this is because the call [RegExp.test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) will automatically call the item's `toString` function for you.

---

## Cyclic bug

However the above code and your code has a dangerous bug that can cause the page to hang, and chew up a lot of memory (depending on the object being searched)

Take for example the following object..

```
const a = [];
a[0] = [a];
```

This will throw a call stack overflow because the data is cyclic.

### Example of call stack overflow error

```js
const a = [];
a[0] = [a];
console.log(filterItem(a, "c")); // Will throw 

/****************************************************************/
/* Cleaned up version of original code as example of cyclic bug */
/****************************************************************/
function filterItem(item, value) {
    if (typeof item == 'string') { return filterString(item, value) }
    if (Array.isArray(item)) { return filterArray(item, value) } 
    return filterObj(item, value);
}
function  filterObj(obj, value) {
    for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        if (key.toLowerCase().includes(value)) { return true }
        if (filterItem(val, value)) { return true }
    }
    return false;
}
function  filterArray(array, value) {
    for (const item of array) {
        if (filterItem(item, value)) { return true }
    }
    return false;
}
function filterString(string, value) {
    return string.toString().toLowerCase().includes(value);
}
```

### Preventing call stack overflow

It is very important that you always protect against this situation. You can use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to check if you have encountered an object before you search it. Each time you search an item you first add it to the set.

### Example using `Set`

const a = [];
a[0] = [a];
console.log(filterItem1(a, "c")); // Will throw

The following is protected against cyclic data but be warned. Any time you call a function in JS you run the risk of running out of space on the call stack.

```
function filterItem(item, value){
    const match = new RegExp(value, "gi");  
    const tested = new Set();
    return (function filter(item){       
        if (!tested.has(item)) {
            tested.add(item); 
            if (item === null) { return false }
            if (typeof item !== 'object') { return match.test(item) }
            return Array.isArray(item) ? 
                item.some(item => filter(item)) :
                Object.entries(item).some(([key, item]) => filter(key) || filter(item));
        }
    })(item);
}
```

You can improve the efficiency by using a [WeakSet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakSet) but you will need to ensure that you don`t try and add strings, numbers and anything that is not an [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

WeakSets do not store the object, only the reference to the hash and thus are quicker and use much less memory.

### Example using `WeakSet`

Note that only objects are added to the weak set.

```
function filterItem(item, value){
    const match = new RegExp(value, "gi");  
    const tested = new WeakSet();
    return (function filter(item){       
        if (!tested.has(item)) {
            if (item === null) { return false }
            if (typeof item !== 'object') { return match.test(item) }
            tested.add(item); 
            return Array.isArray(item) ? 
                item.some(item => filter(item)) :
                Object.entries(item).some(([key, item]) => filter(key) || filter(item));
        }
    })(item);
}
```

Comment: +1, forgot about cyclical in my answer!

Comment: Since there will be a vast amount of things in the search I will use the WeakSet version. I've always been scared of RegExp, today I will finally learn.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are overcomplicating things. You do not need separate logic for `objects` and `arrays`. The following should do the job:

```
function filterItem(item, value) {
    if (typeof item == 'object' || Array.isArray(item)) {
        for (let i in item) {
            if (filterItem(i, value) || filterItem(item[i], value))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    if (typeof item == 'string')
        return item.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase());
    return false;
}
```